# Custom validation segment help for form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I've been using the gen_validatorv4.js script for my site validation for a while. It was here when I started, so I've just kept using it. Can't really back out now. [Here is the information on the script](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml). And yes, I'm aware that it's older and probably not the best script.

My problem is I've got a couple dropdowns for country, state, and province. If you choose the US, state enables, province hides and disables. If you choose Canada, state hides and disables and province is enabled. If you choose another country, they both disable. All that works fine. All the other form fields validate. What I need is one of their custom validation segments that will work with these changing dropdowns. I've attempted quite a few variations, but my JS is very limited and nothing I try is working. It will either ask to verify both fields (whether they're enabled or not) or it won't verify either. Hopefully someone has used this before or at least gets how the custom segments work?

I think I get part of the custom segments, but then I need it to do it's regular validation. I just need for it to check and see if the disabled attr is set for either field and then do one of their regular validation checks for 'required' there. Please help, the deadline looms ominously :(

*also good to know about this script, you can't use the onsubmit function for custom pieces according to their webpage directions.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently after another hour of playing with the code and massive amouts of Googling, I've found a solution. Which I'll post just in case someone else runs into the same problem or something similar.

```
frmvalidator.setAddnlValidationFunction(DoCustomValidation);

function DoCustomValidation(){
  var frm = document.forms["personal_info"];
  //if state is enabled but user didn't choose a state:
  if( ($('#state').attr('disabled') != 'disabled') && ($('#state').val() == '000') ){
    sfm_show_error_msg('Please choose your state.');
    return false;
  //if province is enabled but user didn't choose a province:
  }else if( ($('#province').attr('disabled') != 'disabled') && ($('#province').val() == '000') ){
    sfm_show_error_msg('Please choose your province.');
    return false;
  //if a country is chosen that doesn't have a state or province:
  }else{
    return true;
  }
}
```